# check if a tree is complete standard ml

Tags: function, types, tree, sml, ml

I want to make a function in standard ml that checks if a tree is complete or not, the function somehow works, but its giving me the wrong type and a warning of non-exhaustive cases

The tree code:

```
datatype 'data tree = 
  EMPTY
| NODE of 'data tree * 'data * 'data tree;

fun isComplete EMPTY = true
  | isComplete (NODE(x, y, z)) = if (x = EMPTY andalso z <> EMPTY) orelse (x <> EMPTY andalso z = EMPTY) then false else true;
```

Now the above function's type is: `''a tree -> bool` but the required type is `'a tree -> bool`

The warning I'm having is:

```
stdIn:169.8 Warning: calling polyEqual
stdIn:169.26 Warning: calling polyEqual
stdIn:169.45-169.47 Warning: calling polyEqual
stdIn:169.64-169.66 Warning: calling polyEqual
stdIn:124.1-169.94 Warning: match nonexhaustive
          NODE (x,y,z) => ...
```

What is the problem I'm having?

EDIT:

Thanks to Michael, I fixed the code and now it works:

```
- fun isComplete EMPTY = true
    | isComplete (NODE(EMPTY, _, EMPTY)) = true
    | isComplete (NODE(NODE(x, y, z), _, NODE(a, b, c))) = true
    | isComplete (EMPTY, _, NODE(x, y, z)) = false
    | isComplete (NODE(x, y, z), _, EMPTY) = false;
```

Comment: That EDIT code is still not right. It's not recursive. Those Nodes on the left and right could be not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `''a tree -> bool` type indicates that `a` is an equality type: it must be a type that supports testing with equals. Since you are using `=` and `<>` to test `x` and `z`, the tree data must support equality (even though you're not doing anything interesting with the values). This is the root of the `polyEqual` warning.

The nonexhaustive match warning is more puzzling. When I paste your datatype and function definitions into Moscow ML, I do *not* get a warning. I don't think I'd worry about it too much, as I'd expect fixing the type to also take care of the warning.

To get the desired type `'a tree -> bool`, I'd suggest getting rid of the `if` in favor of pattern matching. E.g.:

```
fun isComplete EMPTY = true
  | isComplete (NODE(EMPTY, _, EMPTY)) = true
  | isComplete (NODE(EMPTY, _, NODE(x,y,z))) = false
  | ... (* fill out the rest of the cases *)
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out the full set of cases, as this looks like homework.

Incidentally, I don't think your test for completeness is correct. Consider what happens when neither subtree is `EMPTY`: you call the tree complete without considering the contents. This doesn't have anything to do with the warnings you're seeing, though.

Comment: i'm using SML/NJ I don't know if its because im using it I'm having the warnings.
Anyway, thanks for the tips I'll be working on it now
Thanks Michael

Comment: @aizen92 I don't have SML/NJ installed, so unfortunately I can't test it there. When you consider that `if`, `andalso` and `orelse` are really just special cases  of pattern matching, it seems likely that SML/NJ and MosML are just transforming the `if` expression into pattern matches with different structures, only one of which is exhaustive. Basic conclusion: favor pattern matching!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the polyEqual warning: in SML/NJ this warning is printed everytime you use this operator, but that doesn't mean your code is faulty. Here's a blog post about it, and in the comments someone explains why the warning is given: http://abstractfactory.blogspot.fr/2006/05/sml-hacking-tip-turn-off-polyequal.html

Comment: okay but what about match non-exhaustive, what cases am I missing?